# Angular 2/4 Emitted Event Not Received?

Tags: angular2-template

(Subtitle: I think my code is haunted...)

I have a parent component with 2 children: Notes and Location.  Location is emitting changes and they are received by the parent.  That is working fine.  Notes is emitting, but apparently it is never received by the parent.

Location input property:

`@Input() public FactLocation :LocationInfo ;  //object initialized later`

Notes input property:

`@Input() public FactNotes : string = "start";`

Location HTML:

`<location-field [(FieldLocation)]="FactLocation" ></location-field>`

Notes HTML:

`<notes-field [(FieldNotes)]="FactNotes"></notes-field>`

Location components input/output:

`@Input() FieldLocation: LocationInfo;
@Output() locationEmitter: EventEmitter<LocationInfo> = new EventEmitter<LocationInfo>();`

Notes component input/output:

`@Input() FieldNotes :string;
@Output() notesEmitter: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();`

Location emitter statement:

`this.locationEmitter.emit(this.FieldLocation);`

Notes emitter call:

`this.notesEmitter.emit(this.FieldNotes);`

When I change the value of the FieldLocation property in my Location child component, the value is reflected in the parent component.  When I change the value of the FieldNotes property in the Notes child component, it is changed locally, but never changed in the parent.

Here are the methods that should be called when an event is emitted from the child components:

```
public FactLocationChange(evt :LocationInfo){       
    console.log(evt);
    this.FactLocation = evt;
}
public FactNotesChange(evt :string){         
    console.log(evt);
    this.FactNotes = evt;
}
```

As near as I can tell, everything is identical between these two, except for the property names and the fact that the Location emitter is signalled in response to a KeyDown event in the child, and the Notes emitter is on a timer (interval).

What am I missing?

Thanks,
Dave

PS: Here's the "haunted" part of the code...the two "Change" methods above that should be called when their event is emitted are actually both **commented out**, but *Location still works*.  I noticed this while debugging - putting a "debugger" statement inside the FactLocationChange method made no difference, even though Location in the parent was being updated.  The debugger never kicked in.

I've tried with the methods commented, uncommented, rebooted, deleted all JS files and had TSC re-generate them, all with no change.  I'm baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not haunted ;)

Actually even though you *think* that the other is emitting, it is in fact not. 
Objects are mutable, therefore the parent will get the value "automatically" for your object `FactLocation`. That's why the parent gets updated even though you have commented the emitting out, like you mentioned at the end of your question. When passing an object like this, you are actually passing a reference of the object in your parent, that is why the change affects the parent.

Primitive types, like your string is not mutable, therefore it's not emitting changes the parent like your object does.

You are mixing the two-way-binding with "regular" `Output` one-way-binding, therefore it's not emitting. If you want to have two-way-binding, as it seems you want, you need to add the suffix `Change` in your emitter, which also needs to have the same prefix (name) as your input. So it should be:

```
@Output() FieldNotesChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

and then emit:

```
public FactNotesChange(evt :string){         
    this.FiedNotesChange.emit(evt)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  I forgot about object references and mutability.  If I have the option, is it better to wrap primitives up in objects and not have to wire up the `@Output`, or stick with the primitive and `@Output`.  Honestly, the magic-name requirements of the Change emitter for @Output to work feels a little hinky.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked out! As to your question...It is totally up to you and your usecase. In this case when you actually want to have the "same data" in both components, you can definitely think about wrapping it up in an Object and skip the Output altogether! :)